# http://example.com/foo/bar loading http://example.com/foo.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I initially thought this was a problem with my .htaccess files, however even after disabling mod_rewrite the problem persisted. http://example.com/foo/bar is loading http://example.com/foo.php with this true for file `foo` being in any folder on the server. Does anyone know what is causing this behaviour and how I can stop this, as I want it to load http://example.com/foo.php?text=bar. I am running a normal LAMP setup, with Ubuntu as the OS.

Also, this happens only on the testing server, not the live VPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews). You can disable it with:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: You, my friend, are the God of Gods. Seriously though, thanks for the answer, you don't want to know how long I spent troubleshooting this